# SpringBoot Application and Hibernate (entityManager is null)

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

I have example SprintBoot application

```
package com.example.demo2;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="com.example.demo2")
public class Demo2Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Demo2Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

My application.properties, here configuration datasource and jpa hibernate

```
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/testdb
spring.datasource.username= admin
spring.datasource.password= admin

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation= true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect= org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= update
```

and i have simple controller method

```
    @GetMapping("/get")
    public List<Movie> getMethod(){
        return myService.myMethod();
    }
```

and service

```
@Service
public class MyService {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;
    @Transactional
    public List<Movie> myMethod() {
        List<Movie> myList = entityManager.createQuery("from Movie").getResultList();
        return myList;
    }
}
```

Result is

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javax.persistence.EntityManager.createQuery(String)" because "this.entityManager" is null
```

I want simple springboot and hibernate application with initialized entityManager for query to db.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by simply replacing all import javax.persistence with jakarta.persistence